# Android: What is the reason for deprecating startManagingCursor?

Tags: android

What is the reason for deprecating startManagingCursor ?

My simple app has a table view with list of data from DB. So, what I have now in onCreate:

```
 final Cursor cursor = getDataFromDB();
 startManagingCursor(cursor);
 setListAdapter(new CursorAdapter(cursor));
```

And thats it, and I dont need to do anything else...

But startManagingCursor is deprecated now, and I should implement LoaderCallbacks , override  onCreateLoader, onLoadFinished, onLoaderReset, create ContentProvider fo my DB and so on. But I dont need all this staff, I just need to get few lines of information from DB. How to be ? Why android did that ? Why should I implement all this staff ?

Comment: I think, you should refer to [Android startManagingCursor is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771582/android-eclipse-startmanagingcursor-deprecated-but-want-to-support-older-api-ver).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That being said, "deprecated" in Android usually means "we will continue to support this, but we think there are better solutions".

If you are willing to inherit from FragmentActivity, you can use the Loader framework implementation in the Android Support package, going all the way back to Android 1.6.

You can certainly use startManagingCursor() on API Level 11+. However, the problems with managed cursors (notably that they requery() on an activity restart on the main application thread) are still there, on older and newer Android versions.

Source: [Android eclipse startManagingCursor Deprecated but want to support older API versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771582/android-eclipse-startmanagingcursor-deprecated-but-want-to-support-older-api-ver)

Comment: -1 Wow, copied-and-pasted *directly* from another user's answer. At least the source is quoted.

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason "why" it is deprecated is that they are really wanting people to adopt ContentProviders.  This is even more apparent as they are pushing `Loaders`, and they provide a `CursorLoader` that only works with `ContentProvider`s (personally that is badly named and should be called `ContentLoader`)

because `startManagingCursor` was in the activity, it made it too easy for people to do (as you are doing in your example) and simply run the db queries on the UI thread, causing pauses and sometimes ANRs.

You could write your own CursorLoader that works with Cursors and not ContentProviders and make it a reusable class so that you can use the `Loader` framework without using ContentProviders.

My solution to this was to simply build a small framework that makes creating content providers a fairly trivial operation, so that I could leverage the existing `CursorLoader`.