# Can I use Deprecated methods?

Tags: android, deprecated

Are there any disadvantages to using deprecated methods in my code?

For example, I am using `view.setBackgroundDrawable(background)` in api 19 and it's working fine, but I want to know the proper way.

Answer (score 9):

The main disadvantage is that the API might not be available in future versions, which will increase the cost of updating your application. It's also an indication that the SDK developers believe that there is a "better way" to do what you want to do.

Thus, in the end, it's a cost/value tradeoff: If the deprecated method is easy to replace, use the replacement. If it isn't, it's up to you to decide whether developing the "future-proof" way is worth the additional effort.

For example:

- `setBackgroundDrawable` can easily be replaced by `setDrawable` (see the comment in the [documentation of `setBackgroundDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))).
- On the other hand, [`startManagingCursor` is much harder to replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099942/android-what-is-the-reason-for-deprecating-startmanagingcursor), so one might put off transitioning to `ContentProvider` until there is no other option.

Comment: I know that but my project has min api 8 and there the the serBackground() method is not supporting,then can I check for the version and use two different methods for the same task?

Comment: If your min api is 8, I don't think there's an alternative to using the deprecated version.