# startManagingCursor(cursor) deprecated method

Tags: java, android, deprecated, android-cursor

I used this code:

```
Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(c);
```

But `startManagingCursor(c)` is a deprecated method. How can i replace it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android eclipse startManagingCursor Deprecated but want to support older API versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771582/android-eclipse-startmanagingcursor-deprecated-but-want-to-support-older-api-ver)

Comment: I googled the exact title of your post and found the answer. Multiple times, in fact. On the same exact site we're on right now. Googling should always be your first step.

Comment: Use model-view-presenter (MVP) pattern with RxJava.  You will get the most flexibility and not be tied to stupid Activity lifecycle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CursorLoader with startManagingCursor()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651680/cursorloader-with-startmanagingcursor)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This method was deprecated in API level 11. Use the new [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) class with [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.

Check out [this tutorial series](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html).